# How can i change device family to iPhone only?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, app-store, app-store-connect

My previous app on appstore has universal device family. Now my app has supported for iPhone only, i have selected

> Target->DeploymentInfo->Devices->Iphone

When i try to upload app it shows error:-

> This bundle does not support one or more of the devices supported by
>   the previous app version.

Upload only work if i selected universal.

Comment: You can not remove support for device, you will have to submit it as a new app.

Comment: @rckoenes if i remove that app from sale & upload. then ?

Comment: Still the same app, so my guess would be no.

Comment: is this still the case? Cant I remove iPhone support on an Univeral app?